# find mac address of all connected systems

Tags: networking, command-line, xubuntu, network-manager, firewall

How can I find out how many system are connected to the local network and how can I get all IP and mac address of these systems.
Is their any command/package to show the IP details?
Can I use this command/package in our Firewall(IP Corp onLinux OS) to block unauthorized systems?

Comment: After I posted an answer, I noticed your comment. It does seem to be a duplicate of that question.

Comment: If you have access to the router the information will you are locking for is shown there.

Comment: See the link to the duplicate, esp. the answer about `nmap`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know a way to actively scan a network for live systems, although I'm sure such tools exist.

However if you just want to know what systems are connected and which MAC address they have I would just have a look at the list of active clients on your router/DHCP server.

You can then enable MAC filtering on your firewall and white list the MAC addresses that you want.

Answer (score 1):

There's a command called `arp-scan` that might do the trick for you, you will need to install it first:

```
sudo apt-get install arp-scan
```

Here's a link to the man pages that will outline how to use it: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/arp-scan.1.html

As an example though, you could do this:

```
sudo arp-scan --interface=eth0 --localnet
```

Where `eth0` is your local ethernet device. You can find out what yours is called via `ifconfig`

Comment: WiFi would be something like `wlan0`.